# How to user ALTER statement with GENERATE ALWAYS INSIDE mysql function?

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

A json array resides in a column product_details in my table product

```
{
"email":"test@test.com",
"street_address#1":"street1",
"street_address#2":"street2",
"given_name":"test",
"products": [ 
                { "product": "product1", "status": "available"},
                { "product": "product2", "status": "not-available"} 
            ]
}
```

The alter table inside my mysql function is not working.

Any help is appreciated.

The mysql function is as follows:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS CREATE_COLUMN;
CREATE FUNCTION CREATE_COLUMN(PRODUCT_ID INT) 
RETURNS MEDIUMTEXT
BEGIN
    DECLARE PRODUCTS, STATUS MEDIUMTEXT;
    DECLARE SINGLE_PRODUCT, SINGLE_STATUS, COL_NAME, COL_VALUE MEDIUMTEXT;
    DECLARE indx INT DEFAULT 0;
        SELECT json_unquote(json_extract(product_details, '$.products[*].product')) INTO PRODUCTS FROM product WHERE product_id = PRODUCT_ID;
        SELECT json_unquote(json_extract(product_details, '$.products[*].status')) INTO STATUS FROM product WHERE product_id = PRODUCT_ID;

        REPEAT
            SET SINGLE_PRODUCT = JSON_EXTRACT(PRODUCTS, CONCAT("$[", indx, "]"));
            SET SINGLE_STATUS = JSON_EXTRACT(STATUS, CONCAT("$[", indx, "]"));
            SET COL_NAME = CONCAT('"','view_products_', TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM SINGLE_PRODUCT), '"');
            SET COL_VALUE = SINGLE_STATUS;

        # This query is not working
            ALTER TABLE product ADD COLUMN COL_NAME varchar(127) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (COL_VALUE) VIRTUAL;

            SET indx = indx + 1;
            UNTIL indx = JSON_LENGTH(PRODUCTS)
       END REPEAT;
    RETURN COL_NAME;
END;

SELECT CREATE_COLUMN (001);
```

Comment: You will need to use dynamic sql mysql doesn't do variable substitution for col_name and col_value.AND I assume you have checked your version of mysql supports generated columns.

Comment: @P.Salmon, I am getting the col_name and col_value when I comment out the ALTER statement and Return the col_name or col_value.

Comment: Agree with @P.Salmon you will need to use [Dynamic SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) as  `VIRTUAL` clause in the Alter Table will not be able to resolve the variable value

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html says:

> SQL syntax for prepared statements can be used within stored procedures, but not in stored functions or triggers.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html says:

> The following additional statements or operations are not permitted within stored functions.
>
> - Statements that perform explicit or implicit commit or rollback.

(ALTER TABLE performs an implicit commit.)

I can't tell what you are trying to do, but you need to think of a different approach.

I recommend you don't use JSON in this way. Store your product data in normal columns, and you won't have to do all this complex stuff with generated columns.